# elasticsearch/kibana query not finding text in _all index

Tags: elasticsearch

We have an elasticsearch kibana setup for storing log files. Log files are written using the Flume elasticsearch sink.

If I search for `@fields.environment:"sm-local-mlamley"` then I find the log events I expect.
These log events have a @message field of `2013-03-04 10:05:41.7262|INFO|FlumePOC.Program|SM 101123123 log message fudgesicle`

However, if I search for `"fudgesicle"` then I do not find them. In fact, I cannot find the entry even if I search for the entire @message field.

How do I go about determining why elasticsearch doesn't seem to be indexing the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can query Elasticsearch directly, like this:

```
http://elasticsearch-host:port/index-name/index-type/_search?q=search-term
```

You can use wildcards for the name and type, including the empty string. And if you add `&pretty` to the end it'll slightly format the JSON response. So you might try:

```
http://elasticsearch-host:9200///_search?q=fudgesicle&pretty
```

That will show you if the log event has made it into ES at all. If it's there you might get some better indication as to the reason that Kibana can't find it.